# In what percentage of test matches did the team lose when enforcing a follow-on?

Tags: cricket, trivia, history

How many times have teams lost the matches when they enforced the follow-on?

Were any of these teams from Asia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of May 2018, there have been [three Test matches won after a team followed on](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283938.html) (winning team listed first):

- [England vs Australia at Sydney in 1894](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/17678/scorecard/62437/australia-vs-england-1st-test-england-tour-of-australia-1894-95/)
- [England vs Australia at Headingley in 1981](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/17031/scorecard/63291/england-vs-australia-3rd-test-australia-tour-of-england-1981/) (part of "Botham's Ashes")
- [India vs Australia at Kolkata in 2001](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/15565/scorecard/63920/india-vs-australia-2nd-test-australia-tour-of-india-2000-01/)

This is out of a total of 2302 Tests matches played to date, so that means that about 0.13% of all Test matches have been won by the team following on.